# jQuery Mobile - button click not working in PageLoad, but works if I try after refreshing the page

Tags: jquery

I have two pages, page #1 being a form and the page #2 being a dialog. I am trying to open page #2 in page #1 through a button click. Unfortunately, it is working as expected but not when the page was launched for the first time. It works only after I refresh the page.

I have tried hard but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your script inside of your page, and wrap your script with pageinit

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="content">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).one("pageinit", function (e) {
                // Whatever script here
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is somehow not too well documented at these 2 places

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/events.html

Comment: Thanks Jeow... I have already kept my script inside page and wrapped the script with pageinit....  Wat else could be the culprit????

Comment: Maybe you have an ID conflict? Since jQuery Mobile keeps both the first and second page inside the DOM, if the first and 2nd page has the same ID, then you'll always end up selecting the ID from the first page. To workaround that, I use $("#IdHere", e.target) where e comes from the pageinit event

Comment: Hi Jeow, Many thx for your advice. I actually missed to see your update on time and I ended up with changing my design and it works as expected though. I will follow your suggestion for sure when I meet up with similar situation. Thanks Again